# Determining the difference between the first number of a matrix and all successive numbers

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of matrices, the first matrix of which looks as follows:

```
$x

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] 
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     
[2,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1     1     0     0     0     0     
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I am trying to create a new matrix of the same dimensions that will indicate the difference in value between the first number of each row and each successive number. Id like to use `abs()` to make this value be the absolute value of this difference. Thus, in the example above, the expected result would be:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] 
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1     1     0     0     0     0     
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

I know that I can use `apply` to see the difference between the first and last columns:

```
abs(apply(x,1,diff, lag=15))
[1] 0 -1 0 -1
```

However, I am not sure how to make this an iterative process in which the lag is increased from 1 to 15 to capture the information for the entire matrix. I also have some NAs in my original matrix, which id like returned as NA in the new matrix.

Ultimately, Id like to use the solution with `sapply` to apply it across my entire list comprised of 500 matrices like the one in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply build a separate matrix from the first column of each original matrix and then take the `abs` of the difference of the two matrices. I'll update in a minute with an example:

Something like this:

```
> m <- matrix(sample(0:1,25,replace = TRUE),5,5)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    0
> m1 <- matrix(m[,1],5,5)
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
> abs(m-m1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    0    1    1
```

And you can easily roll this into a function to apply along your list of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

You mean the difference between the first and each value per row?

For example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> (m <- matrix(round(runif(64)), 4, 16))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
[4,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> abs(m - m[, 1])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
[2,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: +1 For great minds thinking alike...and actually using recycling.

Comment: Yeah. Better for using recycling.

Comment: can you guys explain what 'recycling' is?